# Import EPS from OriginLab with ChemDraw structure into LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pdf, eps

I am using OriginLab to create my graphs for my lab report. For that I would like to add the chemical structure of the organic compound I am analyzing, e.g. Benzene, Benzaldehyde, ...

So basically I am creating the graphs in Origin which works fine and which I can export as EPS (I coulduse another format, but I would like to use a vector grahpic format for keeping the best resultion). Origin only provides (from what I understand) EPS and PDF. PDF seems to hide the atom labels (such as H) and EPS does not show the structures at all.

I have tried importing the structures as images, embedding the strucutres directly as as .cdxml (ChemDraw native format) and export the graph in Origin as PDF and EPS.

I think the problem lies within the EPS settings or sth to do with EPS that it does not show the graphics.

[image: Benzene Structure I would like to add]

What it looks like in Overleaf / TeXStudio / IrfanView:

[image]

My MWE for embeddig the graphics in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{Benzol_Absorbanz_V2.eps}}
    \caption{Benzol Absorbanz}
    \label{fig:Benzol Absorbanz}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The only temporary solution I found is to export it as a .png and then include it into the .tex which is far from optimal because I would like to only have vector graphics.

Comment: I am not familiar with originlab but are you able to export it to a PDF file? If yes, you will have the desired vector graphics quality.

Comment: No pdf does not work either because the H-Atoms on my structure and my axis label seem to disappear when I use PDF. So tried all sorts of embedding the font and using other fonts but that did not seem to work as wanted. 

I found a way around it now. I export the graph as EPS and then add my structure on top in a vector graphic editing software (such as Inkscape). That works fine for me but is quite a inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone looking for an answer to this.

I have found that the easiest way is actually not to try doing everything in one programme but rather use other programmes to get you there

What I mean by that is the fact, that is a lot easier if you just export either as EPS or PDF (even without the box) and just use a vector graphic editing software such as **InkScape**, which makes the whole process a lot easier and manageable.

You can get **InkScape** for **FREE** [here](https://inkscape.org/de/).

So don't try to stick everything together in Origin necessarily, but rather use InkScape to add the individual parts together (a programme which is specifically designed for this purpose).